# Dynamically subtracting one option from another within the same variable (PowerBI)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have data for 8 quarters (but the format of the quarter variable in the data is text, not a date. Its formatted "I - Q1 2022" "II - Q2 2022" and so forth as shown below).

I'm looking to make a dynamic calculation depending on what quarter I pick in the filter, that it will compare this quarters metric score to the previous quarters score.

[image]

For example, here I have clicked Q2 2023 in my filter. The score for Q2 2023 is 11. I now want a KPI that would show +5, since the score for Q1 2023 was 6. (Current Q - Prev Q = New KPI) (11-6=5)

If I chose Q3 2023 in the filter, I would want the KPI to show -3, since Q2 2023 is 11.
(Current Q - Prev Q = New KPI) (8-11=-3)

I just always want the quarter selected to compare to the quarter before it. But since the quarters are listed as text options within one Quarter variable, I'm not sure how to achieve.

(This would be a table calculation in Tableau but not sure how to translate to PowerBI).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a sample .pbix?

Comment: I have one, but how can I upload that here?

Comment: Upload to a sharing site and update your question with a link